# Change default time in insert sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm inserting the date and time into my database, however i'm getting the time wrong because most probably the server is in another country or set up for a different timezone.

```
    $sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE AFNumber='".$_GET["af"]."' AND (".$row['Field']." NOT LIKE '".$_POST[$tempname]."')";
                $result3 = $con->query($sqlCheck);
                if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO `Changes` (`Table`, `AFNumber`, `Attribute`, `DateChanged`, `HRUser`, `OldValue`, `NewValue`)

VALUES ('Employees', '".$_GET["af"]."', '".$row["Field"]."', '".date("d/m/Y h:i:sa")."', '$login_session', '.$row3[$tempname]', '$_POST[$tempname]')";
                    if ($con->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
                    echo "New record created successfully";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql3 . "<br>" . $con->error;
                    }
                }
                }
```

I found this function to fix the problem, but i can't integrate it correctly, any help?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

Comment: If you set the field in MySQL to a datetime field change it to a Varchar of say 50 characters this way however you format your date function it can be recorded onto the database

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` format in `mysql` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` by default. Use -

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Comment: If the column is `datetime` then this format is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found out to get date in the format which you've specified in your code:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    echo "Time is " . date("d/m/Y h:i:sa");
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that (for example) :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Brussels");
$date = date(DateTime::ATOM);
```

So your query become :

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `Changes` (`Table`, `AFNumber`, `Attribute`,  `DateChanged`, `HRUser`, `OldValue`, `NewValue`)

VALUES ('Employees', '".$_GET["af"]."', '".$row["Field"]."', '". $date."', '$login_session', '.$row3[$tempname]', '$_POST[$tempname]')";
```

All the timezone supported :
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php